# Symfony form type inheritance problems

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am building an API using the FOSRestBundle and performing validation using the Types provided by Symfony.

The problem I am facing is that I am trying to find a way to flatten the form type inheritance model that was created when trying to prevent code duplication with inheritance within the form types. This was achieved using the guide on [inherit data option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html).

e.g.

```
....

$builder->add('nested', new NestedType());

....
```

However this has an implication when trying to submit data to the API.

**Currently:**

```
{
    "type": {
        "key": "value",
        "nested": {
            "nested_key": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

**What I am after:**

```
{
    "type": {
        "key": "value",
        "nested_key": "value"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without duplicating the code within the `NestedType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I ended up going with was to extend the NestedType for example:

```
class TypeType extends NestedType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
      ->add('key');
  }

  ....
```

This is less than ideal though since on validation errors the errors in the extended class are hidden only bubbling the error and not what it is associated with.